# Logstash update nested data

Tags: logstash

I'm having a nested field as below

```
"appdata": {
"type":"nested",
"include_in_parent":true,
"properties": {
"accessType": {
"type": "text",
"norms": false,
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
},
"appname": {
"type": "text",
"norms": false,
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
},
"eventtime": {
"type": "text",
"norms": false,
"fields": {
"keyword": {
"type": "keyword",
"ignore_above": 256
}
}
}
}
}
```

I'm updating the same using logstash in output plugin as below

```
elasticsearch
{
hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
document_id => "%{sid}"
index => "dashboard_write"
timeout => 30
script => "if (ctx._source.appdata == null) { ctx._source.appdata = params.event.get('appdata') } else { ctx._source.appdata = ctx._source.appdata + params.event.get('appdata') }"
doc_as_upsert => true
action => "update"
}
```

First time appdata will be null and it should assign that value. For second event, it should append the data to existing appdata
But I saw ctx._source.appdata is empty even though data is there

Am I doing anything wrong here

Comment: I think you should use a filter plugin, not a script in the output

Comment: please update your question with your complete logstash pipeline. where is your data coming from? what is your logstash input? do you have any filters? if possible give more details of what you want to do, what do you expect your output to be.

Comment: Can you please let me know below information is enough??

Answer (score 0):

I'm having input as syslog and filter as below

```
  filter{
 if [I]=="525"
     {
          useragent
          {
            source => "T"
          }
          kv 
          {
            source => "S"
            field_split => ","
            value_split => "="
          }

      mutate 
      {
            split => ["Y", " "]
            split => ["B", "-"]
            split => ["T", "?"]

             add_field => { "sessionid" => "%{[T][0]}" }
             add_field => { "appdata" => null }

          }

     }

     if [I]=="514"
     {    
          mutate
          {
            split => ["T", "?"]

            rename => { "I" => "eventid" }

            add_field => { "sid" => "%{[T][0]}" }
            add_field => { "[appdata][accessType]" => "app1" }
            add_field => { "[appdata][appname]" => "%{F}" }
            add_field => { "[appdata][eventtime]" => "%{timestamp}" }

          }

     }
     }
```

Output looks like below

```
 if[I]=="525"
                {
                   elasticsearch
                    {
                       hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                       document_id => "%{sessionid}"
                       index =>  "dashboard_write"


                    }
                    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
                }
         else if[I]=="514" 
                {
                elasticsearch
        {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        document_id => "%{sid}"
        index => "dashboard_write"
        timeout => 30
        script => "if (ctx._source.appdata == null) { ctx._source.appdata = 
                   params.event.get('appdata') } else { ctx._source.appdata = 
                   ctx._source.appdata + params.event.get('appdata') }"
        doc_as_upsert => true
        action => "update"
        }
                }
```

First 525 event will come. It will be stored with a sessionid and appdata as null. Next event 514 will come with same session id. I'm suppose to update existing 525 record with 514 appdata. Subsequently if multiple 514 events come, just append that to nested object for same session id